# UIImage too many files while cloning UIImage Object

Tags: ios, uiimage, clone

I am creating a single UIImage based on an image file using the following code:

```
UIImage *myImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myImagePath];
```

I'm then looping and adding this myImage to many objects containing a UIImage property.
Which results in me getting the following error:

> error = 24 (Too many open files)

My question is, how do I clone this UIImage without cloning the file reference with it. Which is what seems to be happening.

Comment: Do you alloc/init it each time you need to assign it to a new imageview?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing myobj.graphics = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage]

Comment: Can you include the loop in your question so we can see what youre doing?

Comment: for ( i = 0; i < 25; i++ ) {
        
        myObj *newObject = [myObj alloc];   
         newObject.graphics = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
}

Answer (score 2):

Put this line outside the loop.

```
UIImage *myImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myImagePath];
```

Comment: Sorry, let me add additional information. I'm doing the following inside the loop: 


myObj.graphics = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage]


graphics being a UIImageView which needs to use the myImage.

Comment: And his answer is correct, allocate the image OUTSIDE the loop, and then assign that reference to your graphics object inside the loop

Comment: If I do the allocation outside and assign reference inside the loop, each object will use the same instance of the graphic.  So for example, if I was to do uiimage.hidden = on, all the objects would disappear, which is not the desired behavior. I'm wanting to know how I can copy the original image, without the file reference (if thats even possible). I tried cgimage and back again but I had the same issue.